# Facebook Flow Function Union Type

Tags: javascript, types, static-analysis, flowtype, typechecking

I'm playing around with Facebook Flow and wonder, why does the following function not type check? It obviously uses a union type denoted by '|'.

```
declare var f: ((x: any) => number) | ((x: any) => string);    
function f(x) {
    if(true) {
        return 5;
    }
    else return 'hello';
}
```

The checker complains:

```
function
This type is incompatible with
union type
```

I know that it works when I annotate it like:

```
declare var f: (x: any) => number|string;
```

But why does the former annotation fail? Frankly, I haven't seen union types for function types anywhere so far, however, I don't see a theoretic reason why it shouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((x: any) => number) | ((x: any) => string)` is a valid expression. It means `f` can be one of these two **function signatures**. eg.

`f = function(x: any): number {return 0}` will work

`f = function(x: any): string {return 'hello'}` will also work

`(x: any) => number|string` means the **return value** of the same function can be one of these types dynamically, which is the case here.